# Освобождение памяти, на которую указывают два или более указателей

Tags: c++

```
int *ptr0 =new int(1), *ptr1= ptr0;
std::cout << *ptr0;
delete ptr0;
```

1. Сохранится ли в этих указателях адрес освобожденной памяти?
2. Можно ли освободить память с помощью указателя ptr1? **(delete ptr1;)**.

Язык С++.

Comment: 1. Да.  2. Да.  Только удалять надо один раз.

Comment: @Harry, Спасибо.

Comment: К первому "да" добавлю что значение скорее всего сохранится. Но вы ничего не можете с ним делать без UB. Его нельзя даже сравнивать с `nullptr`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Поскольку в `delete` передача указателя по значению, то "*скорее всего*" мне представляется излишним... А уж значение в переменной, которая не использовалась при освобождении, и подавно...

Comment: @Harry, указатель переданный в `delete` может поменять значение. Если я не ошибаюсь VisualC++ это делает в отладочном режиме. Компилятор может совместить два указателя в одну переменную: до удаления они равны (это доказуемо), после удаления программист не имеет права читать оба указателя. В такой ситуации изменятся обе переменные. Да и вообще, когда речь об оптимизации и UB, я стараюсь быть как можно осторожнее. Поэтому "скорее всего". Обжегшись на молоке дую на воду. :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ну, уговорили...